# Linq Group DataTable Results by Max Value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by

I am working to eliminate some records and trying to use GroupBy in Linq but not having any luck.

```
DataTable prices = (from t1 in product.AsEnumerable()
    join t2 in info.AsEnumerable() on (string)t1["productId"] equals (string)t2["productId"]
    where t1["Date"] == string.Empty || t1["Date"] == null
    select new {
        reference_id = t1["RscId"],
        last_name = t2["Last"],
        first_name = t2["First"],
        credentials = t2["Title"],
        price= t1["price"]
    }
)
.Distinct().CopyToDataTable();
```

I can get the highest prices for each row, but I can't access the other columns using the `g` object with the following code:

```
var result = from row in prices.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new { price= row["price"] } into g
    select new
    {
        HighestPrice = g.Max(x => x["price"])
    };
```

How can I get all the columns from the incoming data, but limit rows to the ones with the max value in a column?

Comment: Sorry, the "price" is actually the sum of multiple bytes that have been added so I can eliminate the records with the lowest byte values while not limiting the results to those where the value is null

Comment: The `g` object is of type `IEnumerable<T>` so you have multiple rows contained in it (you "grouped" the rows). Which row do you want to access the other columns from? If the first, use `g.First()` - etc.

Comment: I need the row with the max "price"

Comment: @Alan that makes no sense, as does your `HighestPrice`. You are grouping by price - every member of `g` will have the same price. So they all have the highest price, the lowest price, etc. You can't "get the highest price for each row", each row only has one price column.

Comment: I am manually parsing a binary database. Some rows I need to strip out and the thing I found to be what was in common was 3 individual bytes that when added together gave me an integer. The rows with the highest integer are the ones I want, even if that highest is 0. By doing this I can eliminate duplicate rows. I stripped my example down to simplify it to a concept rather than a specific use case so that others can benefit as well.

Comment: I think that has just made your query very confusing, especially since your generic code doesn't reflect what you are trying to do. Perhaps redo your question with the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last comment it starts to make sense what you're asking. You have product data of which several products may have identical prices. You want to know the products having the highest price.

So grouping by price is a possible approach. Doing that, you need the group with the highest key:

```
var products = new DataTable();
products.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(string));
products.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
products.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    j++;
    products.Rows.Add(new object[] { i + 1, $"Prod{i:00}", i/10 + 1 });
}

var result = products.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Price"))
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .Take(1);
```

Which gives you (in Linqpad):

[image]

out of three groups with prices 1, 2, and 3.